# How to change style of button and style of icon nested in button by click?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to set function, that if I click on button or icon nested in button, then their style change at the same time. Unfortunately when I'll click on same button, then only its style will change, and icon won't react.

Is there a simple method, that would make it properly?

```
if(e.target.className === 'check-button' || 'fa fa-check'){ //change color
        e.target.closest('.fa-check').style.color = "white";
        e.target.closest('.check-button').style.backgroundColor = "coral";
        e.target.closest('.check-button').style.border = '2px solid coral';                         
    }
```

Comment: Just update your conditional statement to `e.target.className === 'check-button' || e.target.className ===  'fa fa-check'` and it will work fine

Comment: Have a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/jameslafferty/pen/OqBjQN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rummaged in the code and I added classes in css for selected buttons like @jameslafferty. I didn't change my posted code, but I added childNodes[0], in order to add the class 'selected' to a nested icon. Then the button change style with the icon at the same time, regardless of where I click on the button.

```
containerPerson.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.closest('.check-button') !== null){ //adding classes for button and icon
        e.target.closest('.check-button').classList.add('selected');
        e.target.closest('.check-button').childNodes[0].classList.add('selected');
    }
    if(e.target.className === 'check-button' || 'fa fa-check'){ //change color
        e.target.closest('.check-button').style.backgroundColor = "coral";
        e.target.closest('.fa-check').style.color = "white";
        e.target.closest('.check-button').style.border = '2px solid coral';                         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.className === 'check-button' || 'fa fa-check'` This will not compare `e.target.className` to both strings on left. But it will compare it with the first trucy value among left one. You can use array and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Secondly just don't use `closest` again and again store it in a variable and use it

```
if(['check-button','fa fa-check'].some(a => a===e.target.className)){ //change color
        e.target.closest('.fa-check').style.color = "white";
        let elm = e.target.closest('.check-button');
        elm.style.backgroundColor = "coral";
        elm.style.border = '2px solid coral';                         
    }
```

Comment: It will be more good if you just provide a simple solution. If you are adding a new function in your answer that is not yet famous, please explain it.

Comment: @aditya81070 I have explained what is problem in the code and given the solution. You may explain what you want?

Comment: You have used `some() ` function and have written a whole arrow function. So I think, you should explain what `some()` function does.

Comment: @aditya81070 Now I have added a link to documentation

Comment: Unfortunately, that works worse than before. I send a link with the project. When you'll fill inputs by any data, then click confirm and then you will see a new div with check-button. https://codepen.io/danielos12/pen/OqBgVo